# How to make layout like notes in Google Keep using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm making blog template. In article/post list, i want to create layout like this, i don't know what name this layout, it's like notes in android version of Google Keep

[image]

I try to create the layout using simple box div with css float:left but the result is like this, there is a leave blank space when box change line, and the next box start horizontally in new line

[image]

So, is anyone knows how to make layout like that without using two column of div? or maybe there is any javascript plugin to solve?

Comment: http://packery.metafizzy.co/

Comment: idk if Axel's option is the best, http://masonry.desandro.com/ seems like the standard at this point

Comment: that is a nice library Axel, but could you suggest any other?

Comment: try out this [gridalicious](http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a javascript solution, but have you thought of using something like Isotope or Masonry?  http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

> So, is anyone knows how to make layout like that without using two column of div?

It's a bit of feature abuse, but you can set the outer div to use [text columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) and then layout the inner divs in 2 columns with `display: inline-block`.

Column direction flexboxes won't fill the horizontal space automatically even if you allow them break because they only break if they are somehow constrained in that direction and height usually is not constrained in documents.